# Are you colorblind? [survey]

Tags: survey, career

I'm just curious to see how many sound designers here are colorblind. I am red/green colorblind, and over the years I have met quite a few sound designers and musicians that are also colorblind. I wonder if this little genetic wobble has maybe given me (and you?) a friendly little nudge towards sound.

I know that this T-shirt would be my favorite if I could read it:

[alt text http://tshirthell.vo.llnwd.net/e1/shirts/products/a559/a559_bm.gif](http://tshirthell.vo.llnwd.net/e1/shirts/products/a559/a559_bm.gif)

Answer (score 3):

I can read it, but I would give a beer to any colorblind person I encounter wearing that T-shirt.

Self-mockery for the win.

Answer (score 2):

I see it very clear!!! :)

Answer (score 2):

Can't read it. Red/Green colour blind here.

So, anyone want to share what the shirt says?

Comment: @Jason-Job Finally someone else, was getting worried here ;-) It apparently reads: "f*ck the colorblind"

Comment: @Andrew, I can't see it either. Funny, if there were more people who couldn't see it, the "non-color blind" would be the unfortunate ;)

Answer (score 2):

I can read it .

Answer (score 1):

I am indeed not colorblind.  I did, however, get some kind of "friendly" nudge towards sound.  I just haven't figured out what that nudge is yet...

Here's to trying to figure it out!

Answer (score 1):

Nope. No idea what that says. Red/Green color blind as well.

Answer (score 1):

I can't see it either.

Answer (score 1):

I see the text.

Answer (score 1):

Colorblind here.

Answer (score 1):

The colors are blind to me.